# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running Splunk examples and I get an error in this function.

```
var injectCode = function(code) {
    var sTag = document.createElement("script");
    sTag.type = "text/javascript";
    sTag.text = code;
    $(head).append(sTag);
    return sTag;
}
```

The exact error is in `$(head).append(sTag);` . This is placed inside a Jade file and it's running on Node. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT - Sorry, `head` is defined as `var head = $("head");`right above the function.

And `code` comes from this function

```
var getCode = function(id) {
    var code = "";
    $(id + " pre li").each(function(index, line) {
        var lineCode = "";
        $("span" ,line).each(function(index, span) {
            if ($(span).hasClass("com")) {
                lineCode += " ";
            }
            else {
                lineCode += $(span).text();
            }
        });
        lineCode += "\\n";
        code += lineCode;
        });
      return code;
    }
```

Comment: What is `head`? Is it defined before?

Comment: Are you sure `head` exists?  Maybe it should be `document.head`?

Comment: What are you getting the error from?

Comment: Shouldn't there be quotes around `head`, like `$("head").append(sTag);`

Comment: What is this `text` property you're setting?

Comment: Is it possible that you're getting the error from the `code`?

Comment: It's a SyntaxError, not something is missing or reference undefined. Maybe there's an error in JS content you assigned to `sTag`.

Comment: And what about 'code' variable? The error seems to come from here

Comment: You might want to look at what exactly is being set to the text of `sTag`. The syntax error is probably in there.

Comment: Thanks for posting the `getCode` function. To make it sure, could you please also `console.log(code)` and post the one that leads to the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

head is a tag, use that:

```
$('head').append(sTag);
```

**EDIT:**

I would say remove this:

```
lineCode += "\\n";
```

Comment: `This is placed inside a Jade file and it's running on Node. ` - is there something in Node/Jade that defines `head` that would let this work before your change? And you wouldn't get the exception that the OP is reporting if you used `$(head)` and `head` wasn't defined

Comment: @Ian ya true but i don't know what kind of error OP is talking about. Oops sorry, Ian, i saw the title now... **Unexpected token ILLEGAL in jQuery**

Answer (score 1):

Try to exchange `lineCode += "\\n";` for

```
lineCode += "\n";
```

I assume you're dealing with a code string (to which you want to add a newline), not a string literal string (to which you want to add the `\n` literal).